# Errors when opening Nuget Package Manage Console

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2017, powershell-5.0, nuget-console

Whenever I open the package manager console in new VS 2017 session, it shows the below two error messages, and the for all intents and purposes operates normally. At least for vanilla commands like `Install-Package`.

```
Join-Path : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ChildPath'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Dev\.NET\Projects\AcmeSoft\Code\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:13 char:57
+ ... rPackageDirectory = Join-Path $packageDirectory $compilerPackage.Name
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

and

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Dev\.NET\Projects\AcmeSoft\Code\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:14 char:44
+ ... erPackageToolsDirectory = Join-Path $compilerPackageDirectory 'tools'
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

The offending line for the first is:

```
$compilerPackageDirectory = Join-Path $packageDirectory $compilerPackage.Name
```

with the error at `$compilerPackage.Name` (i.e. "char:57")

The offending line for the second is:

```
$compilerPackageToolsDirectory = Join-Path $compilerPackageDirectory 'tools'
```

with the error at `$compilerPackageDirectory 'tools'`.

Can anyone with more Nuget and or PowerShell skills than me explain why this is happening, and how I can fix it, please?

Comment: It seems like both the variables you use might be empty or not contain the content you're expecting. Can you write-host them to see?

Comment: What is your version of Nuget package manager?

Comment: @DavidBrabant `NuGet Version: 3.5.0.1996`

Comment: @Mark I'm not, myself, using any variables nor expecting any content - this has nothing to do with anything I've done. It just magically appeared in 2017 RC, and is still there after upgrading to RTM.

Comment: Seems like a bug. I suggest reporting it to the Dev team.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, thanks. I was just checking if anyone here knew anything, and hoping it wasn't a bug, on the 1st day of RTM as well! I'll log it.

Comment: @ProfK Did you find anything to fix this?

Comment: @JoeBank I had actually totally forgotten about this. I don't think it has occurred again since VS2017 RTM Update 1. I will make a note to always watch for it, and if solved, close this question.

Comment: Exactly the same issue in VS2017, Version 15.4.1